# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")

Tags: python, mysql

I have a common error that occurs in an uncommon way.

So I have a Python script thats running and constantly doing MySQL commands. However, randomly, it will just throw this exception:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

This is a local script working with a local database. It works for the first 1000+ queries, then this exception randomly gets thrown. Nothing that I know of really changes, that's why it's so strange. Sometimes it works for 12 hours, sometimes just 30 minutes before the exception is thrown.

Here is my /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
max_connections=100
max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible you're just running out of simultaneous connections? If you `show status like '%onn%';` from a `mysql` prompt how many are there?

Comment: Tried that command. `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%onn%' at line 1`

Comment: Weird. `show processlist`?

Comment: I use `show processlist` frequently, and it only shows the 4-5 processes I have running. I also reboot everything every 2 days, so nothing should be building up.